# How to hack terminals

Tags: fallout-4

It seems I didn't see the hint while hacking the first terminal *(by the way, is there a way to review all hints already displayed?)*.

So, when selecting a word as possible password, what does the *likeness* score mean? Is the the number of correct letters or correct letters at the correct position?

Comment: it should be stated that fallout-3 and fallout:New Vegas have the same hacking mini-game.   Although, it is a slightly more advanced question, this question asked about fallout 3 and newvegas contains a lot of useful information, http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/124142/30210

Comment: Im shocked no one has mentioned this... But the password is typically related to the context of the terminal. Ie. For a terminal near some untrustworthy characters... pick 'lies' before 'kind'. By using this technique I rarely even have to look at the results. There are normally only 1 or 2 viable options

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to contribute to your likeness score, a letter must be in the correct position.  For the sake of example, let's assume that `CARS` is the correct password.  In this case:

- `BARS` would yield a likeness score of 3
- `CAMP` would yield a likeness score of 2
- `BRAS` would yield a likeness score of 1

It is worth noting that this is not the only mechanic at play - if you find a matching set of parentheses, brackets, or braces ( `(...)`, `[...]`, `{...}`) on the same line, you can click on the leftmost of the pair without using an attempt.  Doing so will either reset your attempts, or eliminate an incorrect password from the terminal.

As pointed out by Nolonar, there are situtations where you can reuse a closing punctuation mark multiple times.  For example, you would be able to use the first two braces within the following string: `{..{..}`.  This does *not* work in reverse - You will only get one use out of the string `{..}..}`.

Comment: Also keep in mind that you can reuse the same closing bracket multiple times, as long as there is a matching opening bracket, so if you see something like `<<>`, you can use `<_>` and `_<>`.

Comment: Good point, I've added it to the answer.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that the parenthesis, brackets, braces, and <> blocks that can be clicked all have to be on the same line. Meaning, for example, the '<' that starts the block has to be on the same line as the '>' that ends it. I've never seen it go over multiple lines.